# Python - How do I split a nested list into further list?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a nested list that is similar to this and sorted on time ascending:

```
[[TIME, 'b', 0],
[TIME, 'b', 1],
[TIME, 'b', 1],
[TIME, 'b', 1],
[TIME, 'b', 10],
[TIME, 'b', 0],
[TIME, 'b', 1],
[TIME, 'b', 1],
[TIME, 'b', 10],
[TIME, 'b', 0],
[TIME, 'b', 1],
[TIME, 'b', 1],
[TIME, 'b', 1],
[TIME, 'b', 1],
[TIME, 'b', 10]]
```

The third item in each list is either a 0, 1 or 10. 0 represents the start, 1 represents moving and 10 represents the finish. How can I split this into a further nested list so I would end up with a list of journeys similar to this:

```
[[[TIME, 'b', 0],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 10]],
[[TIME, 'b', 0],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 10]],
[[TIME, 'b', 0],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 10]]]
```

Comment: Ive been trying to get my head around these but have not been successful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936771/python-how-to-split-a-list-into-an-unknown-number-of-smaller-lists-based-on-a-d

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/python-split-a-list-based-on-a-condition

Comment: That first link is a good one, and has several viable solutions.  Maybe the simplest nontrivial one to start with is the list comprehension one: make a list of the indices which have elements with the last term equal to zero, and then make a new list slicing from each index to the next.

Comment: You can just iterate over the list and add the elements to the sublist until you encounter an item with `10` (like shown in the first of your links).

Comment: I would suggest that you pay attention to the answer by [Cedric Julien](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5936831/577088). The other answers have merits, but they aren't as simple and clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably there's a more pythonic way to do this, but this is functional, straight forward and should be easy to follow. `biglist` holds the initial data.

```
newlist = []
sublist = []
for i in biglist:
    sublist.append(i)
    if i[2] == 10:
        newlist.append(sublist)
        sublist = []
```

gives:

```
[[[TIME, 'b', 0],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 10]],
[[TIME, 'b', 0],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 10]],
[[TIME, 'b', 0],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 1],[TIME, 'b', 10]]]
```

Comment: Well, this was one of the first answers so it was the first I tried and it works perfectly.

Comment: It does seem to add an extra set of opening and closing [] though around the main list

Comment: Upvoted because there's a lot to be said for straightforwardness. Even a non-Python programmer can look at that and figure out what's happening. More importantly, you'll be able to figure it out yourself when you come back next year to maintain it.

Comment: for some reason I seem to get an extra [ at the beginning and ] at the end so instead of just three its four

Comment: @Levon: I can reproduce the extra nesting from this code, FWIW.

Comment: But I fully agree with Kirk, I can actually read this, understand whats happening and learn from it. thikonom's answer below works perfectly too and if I could share my accept with him I would.

Comment: @DSM Never mind ...  my problem was related to *how* I was printing out the result for verification .. "facepalm"

Answer (score 1):

```
#x is your initial list
k, new_list = 0, []
for i,j in enumerate(x):
    if j[2] == 10:
        new_list.append(x[k:i+1])
        k = i+1
```

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the other solution, here we test on whether the journey begins (`d[2] == 0`) instead of when it ends:

```
output = []
for d in data:
    if d[2] == 0:
        # Starting a new journey: we add a new list
        output.append([d])
    else:
        # Continuing a journey: we extend the last list
        output[-1].extend([d])
```

Of course, this gonna fail if the first journey never starts (you'll get an `IndexError` from the `else` statement)...

Comment: It seems to miss the closing of the list on the 10's

Comment: As stated, you don't close the list on a 10, you start a new one (therefore, closing the previous one) on a 0.

Comment: I like this one, although I'd use `.append(d)` instead of `.extend([d])`.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution, if I have understood the question properly:

```
def iter_journeys(lst):
    for e in lst:
        act = e[2]

        if act == 0:
            journey = []

        journey.append(e)

        if act == 10:
            yield journey
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing this, but here's a basic solution:

```
def create_journeys(paths):
  journeys = [[]]

  for path in paths:
    journeys[-1].append(path)

    if path[-1] == 10:
      journeys.append([])

  return journeys
```